Databricks Asset Bundle deployment failing
When I try to validate my Databricks Asset Bundle, I get the following error message:
Run databricks bundle validate
Error: unable to parse response.

I build the wheel successfully in my other YAML file, however when it gets to the validation I get the above error, my databricks.yml is shown below.
bundle:
  name: evals-bundle

# Artifacts section
artifacts:
  # notebooks:
  #   path: notebooks/
  wheels:
    path: dist/

# Workspace configuration
workspace:
  host: ${DATABRICKS_HOST}

# Environment-specific configurations
environments:
  Production:
    workspace:
      host: ${DATABRICKS_HOST}


Could be a network failure.
Or maybe you didn't set the enviroment variable DATABRICKS_HOST.
Try
echo $DATABRICKS_HOST

If it is empty than try:
export DATABRICKS_HOST="https://<databricks-host>"

If it works, than you could make it permanent with:
echo 'export DATABRICKS_HOST="https://<databricks-host>"' >> ~/.bashrc


Tried explicitly defining the HOST, same error, directing me to report it as an issue:
Error: unable to parse response. This is likely a bug in the Databricks SDK for Go or the underlying REST API.

Is your computer able to reach your dabatricks host? Have you also set the $DATABRICKS_TOKEN?
